# Set "experts" on "topics" of my Community?

Tags: customer-community, community

In a Community (open to customer community users), how can I set "experts" on every "topic", so that people can trust their answers more than others? These experts can be part of my organization, but they can also be customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_topics_knowledgeable_people.htm&language=en

Have you looked at above link on how you can Endrose people on specific Topics .

You will manually go and Endrose them and that should toggle them to top .

Comment: Thanks. But I' can't manage to implement these "Knowledgeable people" in my Customer Community, it's like it's only a Chatter feature... Any steps I am missing?